# Congruence modulo 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I have a problem on the congruence of a rather particular quotient to which I cannot see the favorable outcome. What is the remainder of the Euclidean division of $\frac{(7n!)}{7^n\cdot n!}$ by $7$. My reasoning is as follows:

-Let $r$ be the remainder of this Euclidean division.

-We have to ask for the value $r$ between $0$ and $6$ included between $0$ and $6$ inclusive such that : $$\frac{(7n)!}{7^n×n!}\equiv{r}[7]$$

-We can see that the numbers $(7n)!$ and $7^n×n!$ are both multiples of $7$ , so they are by definition congruent to $0$ modulo $7$.

-Thus, the remainder of this Euclidean division $r$ is $r=0$.

(But I doubt very much that this is the case)

Comment: I'm sure you can calculate this directly for small values of $n$. Write down the factors in the numerator as well as the denominator. Cancel all the sevens that appear (check that it appears as factor in both the numerator and the denominator the same number of times), and reduce the others modulo seven. Cases $n=1,2,\ldots$ can be done by hand. What do you get? Do you see any patterns? It may not be obvious in the sense that I don't know the answer. I do suspect that Wilson's theorem may come to the fore. Have you heard of it?

Comment: Hint: $(7n)!/(7 n!)$ is the product of $n, n+1, \ldots, 7n-1$.  Unless $n$ is very small, there is at least one multiple of $7$ there.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The denominator is $7^n\cdot n!$, so $7$ occurs as a factor with multiplicity $n$ plus whatever $n!$ brings with it. I think that all the $7$s cancel in this fraction.

Comment: It might help to write it as $P=\prod_{k\in[1,7n], 7\not\mid k}k$. This product are the same as the numerator except that is missing the factors $(7\cdot 1)(7\cdot 2)...(7\cdot n)=7^n n!$, which gets cancelled by the denominator. Now, separate the factors in $P$ in groups of $6$ consecutive factors. The first are $1\cdot 2\cdot ... \cdot 6$. The factors of all the other groups are congruent to the factors of this. Therefore, $P\equiv (6!)^n\pmod{7}$. You can compute that $6!\equiv-1\pmod{7}$ or appeal to Wilson's theorem.

Comment: The $7^n$ was just $7$ before a recent edit.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The displayed fraction had $7^n$ in the denominator even in the original version. I do see now that the OP had typeset it differently in their in-line version. Judging from the last bullet that was their intention all the time. Sorry, anyway.

Comment: Wilson's theorem, yes I know.
Thanks for your help, I think I can manage.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by looking at the numerator differently. As,
\begin{align}
(7n)! &= (7n \cdot (7n-1) \cdots (7n-6)) \cdot ((7n-7) \cdot (7n-8) \cdots (7n-13)) \cdots (7 \cdot 6 \cdots 1) \\
&= 7^n (n \cdot (7n-1) \cdots (7n-6)) \cdot ((n-1) \cdot (7n-8) \cdots (7n-13)) \cdots (1 \cdot 6 \cdots 1) \\
&= (7^n)(n!)((7n-1) \cdots (7n-6)) \cdot ((7n-8) \cdots (7n-13)) \cdots (6 \cdots 1).
\end{align}
So the quotient becomes, $((7n-1) \cdots (7n-6)) \cdot ((7n-8) \cdots (7n-13)) \cdots (6 \cdots 1).$ Taking indices $\pmod{7}$ and applying Wilsons theorem (or simple inspection for $7$),
\begin{align}
((7n-1) \cdots (7n-6)) \cdot ((7n-8) \cdots (7n-13)) \cdots (6 \cdots 1) &\equiv (6!)^n \\
&\equiv (-1)^n \pmod{7}.
\end{align}

The issue with you logic is you are assuming that as $7$ divides both numerator and denominator, it must divide the quotient. This is not true, as the factors of 7 in the numerator and denominator perfectly cancel in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that $r=1$ if $n$ is even and $r=-1$ (or 6, it's equivalent) if it's odd.

The problem can be solved as follows. First of all, let's determine the ratio between the expression:

$$\frac{[7(n+1)]!}{7^{n+1}×(n+1)!}$$

and the expression:

$$\frac{(7n)!}{7^n×n!}$$

The result will be:
$$(7n+6)(7n+5)(7n+4)(7n+3)(7n+2)(7n+1)$$
which is congruent to $(6!)\pmod{7}$, which is, according to Wilson's Theorem, congruent to $-1\pmod{7}$. Since, conversely,
$$\frac{(7n)!}{7^n×n!}×(7n+6)(7n+5)(7n+4)(7n+3)(7n+2)(7n+1)=\frac{[7(n+1)]!}{7^{n+1}×(n+1)!}$$ it follows that $$r(n+1)=-r(n)$$ and therefore $$r(n+2)=r(n)$$
We can now prove that $r=1$ for even values of $n$ and $r=-1$ for odd values of $n$. Since $r(0)=1$ and $r(1)=-1$, it follows that for any value of $k$, $r(2k)=1$ and $r(2k+1)=-1$